# Spring - Transaction Readonly

Tags: java, spring, transactions, readonly

Just wanted your expert opinions on declarative transaction management for Spring. Here is my setup:

1. DAO layer is plain old JDBC using Spring JdbcTemplate (No Hibernate etc)
2. Service layer is POJO with declarative transactions as follows -
   `save*, readonly = false, rollback for Throwable`

Things work fine with above setup. However when I say `get*, readonly = true`, I see errors in my log file saying `Database connection cannot be marked as readonly`. This happens for all get* methods in service layer.

Now my questions are:

A. Do I have to set `get*` as readonly? All my `get*` methods are pure read DB operations. I do not wish to run them in any transaction context. How serious is the above error?

B. When I remove the `get*` configuration, I do not see the errors. Morever, all my simple `get*` operations are performed without transactions. Is this the way to go?

C. Why would anyone want to have transactional methods where `readonly = true`? Is there any practical significance of this configuration?

Thank you! As always, your responses are much appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[This post](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/04/read-only-transactions-with-spring-and.html) tells that the behaviour or the `readOnly` flag is persistence-mechanism-dependent.

**C.** Yes, when using hibernate, it gives performance benefits by setting the flush mode to `FLUSH_NEVER` (as described in the linked post)

**B.** Yes, JDBC calls do not require a transaction (hibernate requires one), so removing the `@Transactional` configuration trims all transaction management.

**A.** I'd assume spring is calling `connection.setReadOnly(true)` but your JDBC driver doesn't support this

The bottom-line is : don't use `readonly` transactions with plain JDBC.

And another thing - transactions are supposed to span *multiple* queries. Don't make your transactions too fine-grained. Make them [a unit of work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

Comment: Thank you Bozho! Clear as day. I guess I will remove the get* configuration as I am using plain JDBC.

Comment: Without a read-only transaction, you also open yourself up to the dreaded `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

Comment: In what way can I avoid org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException while suing waffle authntication manager.

Comment: Post Link is broken [link](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/04/read-only-transactions-with-spring-and.html)

Answer (score 5):

> A. Do I have to say get* as readonly? All my get* methods are pure read DB operations. I do not wish to run them in any transaction context. How serious is the above error?

Actually, you probably still want to run all of your `get()`s in the context of a transaction, to make sure that you are getting consistent reads. If on the other hand, you don't care about this, you can set the transaction level accordingly.

> C. Why would anyone want to have transactional methods where readonly = true? Is there any practical significance of this configuration?

1. To help protect against errant writes within get()` methods
2. For optimization purposes. Not only can Hibernate make use of this information, as Bozho mentioned, but some databases/JDBC drivers can also be make use of this info.

Comment: Thank you Matt! I guess my get* methods are pretty much simple independant SQL select queries and I am not using Hibernate, so I'll turn off the setting.