# @Transactional creates a new reference dirty object even when it is not modified

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

When used `@Transactional` annotation in a method and we do not modify the domain object, still a new reference of the new object is committed.

For example lets take a sample case:

Domain Object:

```
@Table(name = "SAMPLE_TABLE")
public class SampleTable{        
    @Column(name = "ID")
    String id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    String firstName;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    String city;

    @Column(name = "STREET_ADDRESS")
    private String streetAddress;
}
```

And I have a service method with `@Transactional` annotation but doesn't modify the domain object.

```
@Transactional
public void doNothing(String id) {
    SampleTable sampleTable = sampleTableRepository.findById(id);       
}
```

So, whenever `doNothing`method is executed, I see the domain object becomes dirty since a new reference with no change in data is committed.(Confirmed this using Hibernate Interception `findDirty` method). When I remove the `@Transactional` this(dirty object) doesn't happens.

Is this a normal behavior or a bug in Hibernate.

Comment: Can you add the code for `Model` too?   I assume you haven't overridden the method `findById` on the spring repository. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I removed the model class. It just had a generated String id. I now added id to the existing class. I have a method SampleTable findById(String id); in the interface SampleTableRepository which I have created.

Comment: I think it a read only issue: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539213/why-do-i-need-transaction-in-hibernate-for-read-only-operation)

Comment: @hasnae: Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's not "NORMAL" behaviour by the JPA spec, and I wouldn't expect other implementations to do that. Nothing should be "dirty" there (as you say).

Comment: @NeilStockton: Can you give the link for the JPA spec where it is saying that it is normal. I am not able to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of [complicated configuration options](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) for transactions in Spring. It's worth adding [@ReadOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562865/spring-transaction-readonly#2562960) to transactions that you are certain really are read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate apply a strategy ( inspection ) to detect dirty objects (for example If the object is still transient then it is always dirty.). So to avoid dirty check use the readonly annotation ( The point 5. from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539213/why-do-i-need-transaction-in-hibernate-for-read-only-operation): Another thing when it comes to Hibernate, Spring sets the FlushMode to MANUAL in case of read-only transactions, which leads to other optimizations like no need for dirty checks.)

Comment: The information is useful. But, my actual question is why is the object dirty when it is not modified by the method.